# Cascade delete in cloudcode on user

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm attempting to trigger a cascade delete when a user is removed but the `find()` to find the related items doesn't appear to be running.

My hook is as follows:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeDelete(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
  var user = request.object;
  console.log('User is ' + JSON.stringify(user));

  var checkInQuery = new Parse.Query('checkIn');
  checkInQuery.equalTo('user', user);
  console.log('Query is ' + JSON.stringify(checkInQuery));
  checkInQuery.find().then(function (checkIns) {
    console.log('Success');
    Parse.Object.destroyAll(checkIns);
  },
  function(error) {
    console.log('Error');
    console.error('Failed to delete user checkins: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
  });
  response.success();
});
```

Which I want to use to remove all instances in the checkIn table which belong to the to-be-delete user.  However when I look in my logs I see:

```
I2014-08-01T17:48:05.807Z] User is {"username":"user_test_103075160","objectId":"t4vtXULwo9","createdAt":"2014-08-01T17:48:00.690Z","updatedAt":"2014-08-01T17:48:02.186Z"}
I2014-08-01T17:48:05.809Z] Query is {"where":{"user":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"t4vtXULwo9"}}}
```

But nothing in terms of a response from `checkInQuery.find()`.  I expected to see either `Success` or `Error` as per the log messages.

Comment: Not sure, but can it be because you are calling `response.success()` right after `find()`? Instead try to call it in the success callback of `find()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, turns out that it was a combination of this and permissions which was causing the failure.

Comment: Can you provide some more details about what permissions you were lacking?

Comment: @adamport it was due to the user not having full permissions on their checkins.